# TCPDF breaking my output on PDF

Tags: php, css, pdf, opencart, tcpdf

I am using open cart. I am generating a PDF file using TCPDF. I load my html from a tpl file, which has form with dynamic data. here is my code

```
$pdf = new TCPDF()
$pdf->AddPage('P');
$html = $this->render();
$pdf->writeHTML($html);
$pdf->Output();
```

Its showing me output but its breaking the result.
I have five parts in my form but its just showing me first two why is this so.
Plus my css is not working well.